# Why does my application close when a random character is pressed?

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I have this console application, It's very basic as you can see and im trying to make it to where when it says

> Console.WriteLine("Would you like to go back to the main menu? Y/N");

And lets say i dont press either Y or N.. But instead lets say F the application just closes.. How come? 
And what methods should I use to resolve this issue?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Game
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            startMenu();


        }

        public static void startMenu()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("======= Welcome To The Player Registry =======");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Name");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Age");
            Console.WriteLine("3. City");

            try
            {
                int value = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                int answer = value;
                switch (answer)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("======= Player Names=======");
                        Console.WriteLine("Jonsson, Adam");
                        Console.WriteLine("Jetsson, Carl");
                        Console.WriteLine("Jimmy, Golf");
                        Console.WriteLine("Ali, Mohammed");
                        Console.WriteLine();

                        Console.WriteLine("Would you like to go back to the main menu? Y/N");
                        string choice = Console.ReadLine();
                        if (choice.Equals("Y", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || choice.Equals("y", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            Console.Clear();
                            startMeny();
                        }
                        if (choice.Equals("N", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || choice.Equals("n", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            Console.Clear();
                            Console.WriteLine("Okay.. Bye!");
                            Console.ReadKey();
                        }
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        Console.WriteLine("Look it works!");
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("What?..");
                        return;

                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: follow the logic.  if the `choice` is not `Y` or `N`, then you break out of the switch...and then that's the end of the program.

Comment: Do not use try-catch in this way. Instead use the TryParse method on the line read from the console.

Answer (score 0):

It close when you hit any other keys because the application completed executing. In order to force application to wait, then you need to add line `Console.ReadLine();`. In your case you can change code to this

```
if (choice.Equals("Y", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || choice.Equals("y", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    Console.Clear();
    startMeny();
}
else if (choice.Equals("N", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || choice.Equals("n", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("Okay.. Bye!");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
else
{
  Console.WriteLine("Wrong Key");
  Console.ReadLine();
}
break;

case 2:
    Console.WriteLine("Look it works!");
    Console.ReadLine();
    break;
default:
    Console.WriteLine("What?..");
    Console.ReadLine();
    return;
```

Answer (score 0):

The console app is closing because it will only run until it has nothing more to do. A good way to avoid closing the program is to give the user the option to do something else.

These all need more code to match your project, but here is just a quick idea:

you could create a few methods to help you out:

```
 public static string BackToMainMenu()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Would you like to go back to the main menu? Y/N");
        return Console.ReadLine(); ///returns the user's choice in a string variable
    }

 public static void CheckChoice(string choice)
    {
        if (choice == "y")
        {
            ///back at menu stuff goes here
        }

        if (choice == "n")
        {
            ///whatever you want to do on "n"
        }

        ///if user types anything other than y or n (could also use 'else')
        if (choice != "n" && choice != "y")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Input");

            ///Ask user if they want to go back to menu (again) 
            ///check their choice
            CheckChoice(BackToMainMenu());
        }
    }
```

replace what you have under case 1 with:

```
   case 1:
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("======= Player Names=======");
                    Console.WriteLine("Jonsson, Adam");
                    Console.WriteLine("Jetsson, Carl");
                    Console.WriteLine("Jimmy, Golf");
                    Console.WriteLine("Ali, Mohammed");
                    Console.WriteLine();

                    ///ask "back to menu?" and check choice
                    CheckChoice(BackToMainMenu());
```